# Need regular expression to validate username

Tags: regex

Need a regular expression to validate username which:

1. should allow trailing spaces but not spaces in between characters
2. must contain at least one letter,may contain letters and numbers
3. 7-15 characters max(alphanumeric)
4. cannot contain special characters
5. underscore is allowed

Not sure how to do this. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

This is what I was using but it allows space between characters

```
"(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9_]{1}[_a-zA-Z0-9\\s]{6,14}"
```

Example: user name
No spaces are allowed in user name

Comment: Why must you use a single regexp for this?  Often a few lines of clear code are better than a single contorted regexp.  Allowing trailing spaces seems odd; are they actually part of the username, or are they ignored?  Do you really want to treat "fred" and "fred " as distinct?  Do trailing spaces count towards the 7-15 maximum length?  Must a username be *at least* 7 characters, or is there a variable maximum length that can be anywhere from 7 to 15 (and based on what)?  What exactly are "special characters"?  Is "123_456" valid (i.e., does underscore count as a letter for purposes of rule 2)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
foundMatch = Regex.IsMatch(subjectString, @"^(?=.*[a-z])\w{7,15}\s*$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Is also allows the use of `_` since you allowed this in your attempt.

So basically I use three rules. One to check if at least one letter exists.
Another to check if the string consists only of alphas plus the `_` and finally I accept trailing spaces and at least 7 with a max of 15 alpha's. You are in a good track. Keep it up and you will be answering questions here too :)

**Breakdown:**

```
    "
^           # Assert position at the beginning of the string
(?=         # Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead)
   .        # Match any single character that is not a line break character
      *     # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   [a-z]    # Match a single character in the range between “a” and “z”
)
\w          # Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, etc.)
   {7,15}   # Between 7 and 15 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\s          # Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
   *        # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
$           # Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any)
"
```

Comment: Hi, The above expression you provided still allows space in between characters

Comment: @user1078081 Yes? Can you explain me how this is possible?

Comment: This shows a invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \ ) syntax error pattern. How can I fix it.

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: @NotEmpty 
@Pattern(regexp = "^(?=.*[a-z])\w{7,15}\s*$"
private String username;

Comment: Is this for Hibernate?  You probably need to use double backslashes as you did in your original regex.

Comment: Yes I am using hibernate validator

Comment: +1 but one minor nit-pik: The `\w` allows underscores and the OP stated: _"alphanumeric"_ and _"letters and numbers"_.

Comment: @ridgerunner I specifically commented on it : Is also allows the use of _ since you allowed this in your attempt.

Comment: @user1078081 Sorry didn't know your regex engine :)